# rails vendor folder angular2 development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, angular

Hello very amazing coders,

I'm currently using npm to manage angular2 dependencies. I then manually copy the required angular2 files from `node_modules` into my rails `vendor` folder. The rails will make those files available for me to load. However, I've read that vendor files should not be in source control. Ok, fair enough, I agree. However, if I .gitignore these files, they do not make it onto heroku. And subsequently my `<script></script>` tags in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` return 404's not found.

I'm looking for overall guidance on how you guys do vendor assets in production vs. development? In my case, a gem for angular2 source files does not exist, so pretend that is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's so many flavors for this and as everything else it depends on your project. Here are some:

1- You can use cdn versions of the libraries in production, which is supposedly better because there's a good chance that people visiting your page would have already downloaded jquery or w/e from a cdn while visiting another page so you they don't have to download yet another copy for your page alone. Like https://www.maxcdn.com/ or https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/.

2- You can have one repo with your code on it, sources and all, without the vendor files and one more repo connected to heroku where you push only the distributable build of your project including if you want, the vendor files.

3- Run the same npm install and all other configuration scripts you normally use from your production server, Heroku should allow you to do this np, or at least have a plugin for it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh. If I create an npm script that runs on production, I won't have to have the assets in source control.